# Not displaying horizontal and vertical list in fragment

Tags: java, android

Creating a tabbed fragment activity, in my home_fragment i am trying to display a horizontal and a vertical list view, but its not displaying the list, below is my code of home_fragment for onCreateView() method --

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        horizontalList = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recycler);
        verticalList = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyle_view);

        horizontalList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        verticalList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //set horizontal LinearLayout as layout manager to creating horizontal list view
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        horizontalList.setLayoutManager(horizontalManager);
        horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalListAdapter(getActivity());
        horizontalList.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);

        //set vertical LinearLayout as layout manager for vertial listview
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        verticalList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        verticalAdapter = new VerticalListAdapter(getActivity());
        verticalList.setAdapter(verticalAdapter);

        return v;
    }
```

Is there any changes to be made here.

HorizontalListAdapter.java --

```
public class HorizontalListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private Activity activity;

    public HorizontalListAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_horizontal_list, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HorizontalListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Position clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    /**
     * View holder to display each RecylerView item
     */
    protected class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        }
    }
}
```

item_horizontal_list.xml--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/mountain" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you share adapter code?

Comment: @R2R........shared the code of adapter

Comment: Can you share your layout  `item_horizontal_list`

Comment: @R2R..........shared item_horizontal_list.xml code

Answer (score 0):

> Not displaying horizontal and vertical list in fragment

in your **`onBindViewHolder`** you are no displaying any data check out your adapter class

You need to set any data inside your `onBindViewHolder` like this

**Sample code**

```
public class HorizontalListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Activity activity;

    public HorizontalListAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_horizontal_list, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HorizontalListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Position clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.edtName.setText("NILU");
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    /**
     * View holder to display each RecylerView item
     */
    protected class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private LinearLayout linearLayout;
        TextView edtName, edtPhone, edtPass, edtAdrress;
          ImageView imageView;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            edtName = view.findViewById(R.id.edtUname);
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        }
    }
}
```

Changes in your layout you need to set id to your `imageview` and `textview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/mountain" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edtUname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here is the good tutorial of **[Android working with Card View and Recycler View](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)**